# MSSQL Server 2012 and pypyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, odbc, pypyodbc

I am running an application on linux machine and database mssql server.
We use pypyodbc to connect to the db server with ip and port.

```
    conn_str = "DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=192.168.0.1;PORT=1433;DATABASE=xxx;UID=sa;PWD=xxx;TDS_Version=8.0"
    pypyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

But now I need to connect to db server with the windows authentication name like.

```
Database Instance Name: INST1
DB login: INST1\SQLEXPRESS
```

How can I add this into connection string.

I am getting error like this

```
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: (u'08001', u'[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source'
```

But with the ip I can connect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect by instance name, the SQL Browser service must be running on the SQL Server machine. Once that condition is met, a connection string like

```python
conn_str = r"DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=192.168.1.122\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=myDb;UID=sa;PWD=whatever"
```

will work.